# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 - Can we Integrate Estimote Ibeacons with IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, estimote

Currently I'm working on IBM Mobilefirst and estimote ibeacon Integration. I didn't found any document for developing Hybrid Application using estimote Ibeacon API.

Can we integrate Estimote Ibeacons with IBM MobileFirst.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything unique to estimote beacons? There are many types of beacons, so it does not make sense to provide something particular to one set of beacons.

MFP provides the following tutorial for integrating with beacons in iOS and Android. You can attempt following it: [Working with Beacons](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/advanced-topics/working-with-beacons/)

Comment: Thanks @Idan for the response, As I gone through this document It seams like Native Application Development. Is there any estimote JS API for hybrid application ?

Comment: There is no JS API available.

Comment: I found one Estimote iBeacons PhoneGap plugin. but here they used EVOThings. What My doubt is can we use this phonegap API in MobileFirst or not . Once look into this document https://github.com/evothings/phonegap-estimotebeacons

Comment: If the plug-in requires use of Cordova Plugman to install the plug-in it is not possible to use it. Otherwise you could follow the Cordova plug-ins tutorial to manually re/create this plug-in inside your project, likely not an easy task.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Idan for providing valuable information.